# 任意ドメインを登録するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Tags: network

昔は[bitnet](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bitnet)というドメインがあったと聞きましたが、これはどのようにして任意のドメインを取得したのでしょうか？

昔に可能だったが今はできないためか、調べてもその方法が出てこず、どうすればいいのかわからない状態です

それとも条件付で使用場面が限定されるからあまり紹介されないのでしょうか?
もしそうだったとしても、どのような仕組みでこのように任意ドメインを取得できるのかが知りたいです

---

### 追記

少し調査を進めたところ、[擬似トップレベルドメイン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%96%91%E4%BC%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3)というものが近いと思います。
しかし、記事には原理が書かれていないので詳細な方法がわかりませんでした。

Comment: 任意ドメインとはどのようなものを指していますか？

Comment: 少し調査を進めたところ、擬似トップレベルドメインというものが近いと思います(https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%96%91%E4%BC%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%99%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3 ) しかし、記事には原理が書かれていないので詳細な方法がわかりませんでした

Comment: やりたいことを具体的に書かれるとよいかと思います。イントラネット上でホスト名を使って通信したいのか、ドメインを取得して広くThe Internetに情報を公開したいのか。やりたいことによって回答が変わりそうです。

Answer (score 3):

自分の管理下にある環境で、任意のドメイン（TLD含む）を任意のIPアドレスに対して登録する方法を2つ紹介します。

## /etc/hostsに記載する

例えば、 `/etc/hosts` に `127.0.0.1 example.stackoverflow` という記述を行うことで、ブラウザや`curl`からexample.stackoverflowというURLに対してリクエストを行うことで `127.0.0.1` に名前解決が行われるようになります。

ただし、この設定は端末毎に行う必要があり、複数のマシンで同様にアクセスできるようにしたい場合は下記のDNSサーバを立てる方法が良いでしょう。
なお、`/etc/hosts`はUnix系OSでの設定で、Windowsでは `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` というファイルに相当するようです。

## 自前でDNSサーバを立て、設定を記述する

DNSサーバの中でIPアドレスと指定したいドメインの対応を設定し、各マシンで立てたDNSサーバを利用する設定を行うことで同様に名前解決を行うことができます。Unix系OSでは `/etc/resolve.conf` 、Windowsでは `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` というレジストリから設定できるようです。

また、DNSサーバの例としては、歴史が長いBINDや、近年活発に開発されているCoreDNSなどが有名でしょう。

Answer (score 2):

Bitnetは、世界最初のWorld Wide Web(WWW)サイトの公開(1991年。CERNのバーナード・リーによる）よりも前の1981年に運用が開始されています。
まだ、WWWが無い時代に大学の計算機の間を接続する仕組みとして始まったのがBitnetです。その頃は、IPドメインを管理するIPNICなどの組織は存在しませんし、IETFも存在しません。IPドメインの管理の仕組み自体が無かったのです。
後に、IPドメイン管理などが整ってきて、大昔のBITNETが今なら何に当たるのかという考察において「擬似トップレベルドメイン」に近いという話になったのです。

自分が好きな名前を付けたければ、現時点で世の中に存在しない（世の中の人の誰の思索にも存在しない）ものを考案してください。そうすれば、それに好きな名前を付ける事ができますよ。